# Put a button in the creation of a model

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

I would like to make sure that in addition to the title, color and description, I would like to make sure that when I create a model it makes me choose which url to render it when Ia person clicks the button. It's possible?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from colorfield.fields import ColorField

class Aziende(models.Model):
    immagine = models.ImageField()
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    prezzo = models.FloatField()
    descrizione = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    nome_color = ColorField(default='#FF0000')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Aziende"
```

home.html

```
[...]
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    {% for Aziende in Borsa %}
    <div class="col"><br>
      <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="{{ Aziende.immagine.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="title" style="color: {{Aziende.nome_color}}" >{{Aziende.nome}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{Aziende.descrizione}}</p>
        <p class="card-text fst-italic text-primary">Valore Attuale: €{{Aziende.prezzo}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Più info</a>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
[...]
```

urls.py (1)

```
[..]
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Borsa/', include('Borsa.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root =settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

urls.py (2)

```
[...]
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Borsa),
    path('Investimenti', views.Investimenti, name='Investimenti'),

]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean Drop Down Menu ?

Comment: No one button...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/admin/">admin</a>
    <a href="/Borsa/">Borsa</a>
    <a href="/accounts/">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the support but I understood that. I intend to put each model I create a button with a different url each. How do I get it from the database?

Comment: Did you have created any URLs until now ? That you wanna put at frontend for navigation.

Comment: Yes I have those.

Comment: Ok, I did it. ,.,

Comment: I edited my answer, is that what you wanted to do ?

Comment: No, I want to decide which link to put on the button. For example, if I add a "Company" it makes me choose the name etc ... I want it to do the same thing with the button (to make me decide which link to put on the button). It can be done?

Comment: For this type of functionality you have to create a Separate view. This can't be handled via html only.

Comment: And how do I do this? Thanks so much

Comment: Sorry I know the way how to do this in react.js for dynamic user interfaces. But using Django, I'm not sure how to do that. Or somehow we have to use JavaScript at frontend. Because in Django there is a problem if we want get data or post after hitting DB, page gets reload. So that can't be achieved using just Django either. But in React.js we can achieve this by useState and there are alot of other ways in react to achieve that.